# Query to select: who two employee works for the same company

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose that we have following tables:

```
company             company_has_employee        employee
-------------------------------------------------------------
id                  company_id                  id  
companzy_name       employee_id                 emplyee_name
```

How to create SQL Query, which retrieves any two employees, who works for the same company and what is this company?

Comment: just so this is clear, you want a company that has exactly 2 employees?

Comment: i am lost here.. two employees? is that mean company has ONLY TWO Employees or ANY TWO EPLOYEES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming juergen d's joins of the table are correct, I will modify the query to

```
select top 2 company_name, e.employee_name
   from compyny c
   join company_has_employee ce on ce.company_id = c.id
   join employee e on e.id = cs.employee_id
   group by company_name
   having count(e.id) > 1
```

This will always return the top 2 employees

juergen d's original query will always return the first and last employees based on their ID.

If you want two employees chosen randomly, then you can try this:

```
select top 2 company_name, e.employee_name
   from compyny c
   join company_has_employee ce on ce.company_id = c.id
   join employee e on e.id = cs.employee_id
   group by company_name
   having count(e.id) > 1
   order by RAND((e.ID)*DATEPART(millisecond, GETDATE()))
```

The last order by clause will change the order of records randomly and you will always get the top 2 of a random order...which means 2 random employees will be selected each time the query is run.

Answer (score 1):

```
select company_name, 
       min(e.employee_name) as emp1, 
       max(e.employee_name) as emp2
from compyny c
join company_has_employee ce on ce.company_id = c.id
join employee e on e.id = cs.employee_id
group by company_name
having count(e.id) > 1
```

Comment: Could you please, explain, how given aggregate functions (min,max) works in this context?

Comment: You said you need 2 employees for every company having at least 2 employees. If you group by the company then you can use `min()` and `max()` to get 2 employees for every company. The DB will use the minimal name alphabetically and the maximum name alphabetically.

Comment: Do you want your SQL to randomly select any two employees? i.e. each time the query is run, the result may be different. Is that correct?

Comment: @Swagata It is OK. But, If you have any other solution, can help.